# Creating view filter that lists most recent, except the x most recent

Tags: views

I'm trying to create a view that will go on a front page where the three most recent articles will be featured content displayed in a slideshow. I've got that working, but my issue is displaying the rest of the most recent articles in another view, as a list formatted normally as they appear in the teaser display. My problem isn't achieving that display, it's filtering the articles properly so I get most recent - 3 most recent. I'm trying to not be redundant on this articles page.

If my approach of creating two different views to achieve this effect is totally misguided, or if there's some other glaring way to do this more easily, please correct me. I'll be very grateful.

For clarity, I'm including a rough sketch, where the numbers indicate the recentness of the article and the top unit is the featured content slideshow display:
[image: The numbers indicate the recentness of the article]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a view and have two different displays. One display holds your slideshow thing and the other display holds the rest of the items.

The second display would be set to have the style item list and the pager settings should be set to have an offset of three. The offset will skip the first X items that are present in your first display.

[image]